# GCC : Unscoped enumeration type give an ambiguity error

Tags: c++, gcc, enums, c++14, language-lawyer

In the following code, I have defined an **[unscoped enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)** with `long long` type. This program works fine on **Clang**.

But **GCC** compiler gives an ambiguity error.

```
#include <iostream>

enum : long long { Var=5 };

void fun(long long ll)
{
    std::cout << "long long : " << ll << std::endl;
}

void fun(int i)
{
    std::cout << "int : " << i <<  std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    fun(Var);
}
```

GCC generated error :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:12: error: call of overloaded 'fun(<unnamed enum>)' is ambiguous
     fun(Var);
            ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: void fun(long long int)
 void fun(long long ll)
      ^~~
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: void fun(int)
 void fun(int i)
      ^~~
```

Why does GCC compiler give an ambiguity error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GCC is wrong.

Unscoped enumeration type converting to its underlying type is qualified as [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion):

> an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed can be converted to its underlying type, ... (since C++11)

While for `Var` converting to `int` it requires one more [integral conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) (from `long long` to `int`). *Integral promotion* has higher ranking than *integral conversion* in [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences):

> 2) Promotion: integral promotion, floating-point promotion
>
> 3) Conversion: integral conversion, floating-point conversion,
>   floating-integral conversion, pointer conversion, pointer-to-member
>   conversion, boolean conversion, user-defined conversion of a derived
>   class to its base

Then `fun(long long ll)` should be better match.

---

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82307)'s the gcc bug report; it's been fixed at 2017-10-24. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SwFgo4yXdZwOTkMS)